# How can I figure out which file / gem is monkey patching a method?

Tags: ruby

There is a Gem in my dependency list that is Monkey Patching to_json on String.

How can I figure where this monkey patching is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`source_location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location).

> Returns the Ruby source filename and line number containing this method or nil if this method was not defined in Ruby (i.e. native)

```
$ cat monkey.rb
class String
  def reverse
    ""
  end
end

p String.instance_method(:reverse).source_location
$ ruby monkey.rb
["monkey.rb", 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
puts String.instance_method(:to_json).source_location
```